# I trying to use asterisk... how to set the iptables?

Tags: asterisk, iptables

I install asterisk on centos 6.5 32 bit.

That's great.

User register is no problem.

And calling is no problem, too.

but... i can't hear anything.

so, I stop the iptables service.

then..i can hear sound.

how to modify iptables?

my iptables is below.... and i use port 5060.

```
# Firewall configuration written by system-config-firewall
# Manual customization of this file is not recommended.
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT[0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5060 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5070 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5080 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 5060 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 5070 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 5080 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need allow rtp data(sound). If you not changed rtp.conf, value have be like this:

```
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 10000:20000 -j ACCEPT
```

Note, it is also **highly** recomended install fail2ban on all your sip ports. Otherwise very likly your server will be always down becuase of fraud bots.